# Не передается переменная в php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

В фале functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );

function ajax_form(){
    global $postId;
    $postId = $_REQUEST['name'];
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ){
        echo $postId;   
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

В файле publications.php

```
$('.pages_list a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    postId = $(this).attr('data-catid');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_order',
            name: postId
        },
        success: function (response) {
                var content = "<? echo $postId; ?>";
                $("#thumbs").html(content);
        }
        });
    });
```

В publications.php переменная $postId не выводится, но она есть в  response.
Как вывести переменную php  $postId  в publications.php?

Comment: А как она должна попасть в атрибут `data-catid`?

Comment: Вам ajax возвращает ответ из php в переменную response вот её и выводите

Comment: Она мне она нужна как переменная php для того чтобы вывести посты в worpdress из рубрики по id

Comment: В data-catid она попадает потому что  при клике на ссылку у нее есть такой атрибут data-catid = '.$catId.'